# Compilation Error

Tags: c#, class, webforms

Im getting a compilation error when running this code:

```
    namespace WebApplication1
{

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

   private Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // let's ignore case when comparing.

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:/dictionary.csv")))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] tokens = reader.ReadLine().Split(';');
                _dictionary[tokens[0]] = tokens[1];
            }
        }
     }



    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            string output;
            if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(TextBox1.Text, out output))
                   {
                    TextBox2.Text = output;
                   }
             else
                   {
                    TextBox2.Text = "Input not recognised";
                   }   
    }
  }    
}
```

Here is the Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'TextBox1_TextChanged' and no extension method 'TextBox1_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webform1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What does this mean and how can I correct it?
Thanks

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: In your aspx page you have defined an event against your `TextBox`, later in your code behind you are missing the event handler, Either remove that from your aspx page or create a new event hanlder for your `TextBox1_TextChanged` in your cs file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very probably on your Form, in Visual Studio, there is a `TextBox1_TextChanged` method declared in the `TextChanged` property of your `TextBox`, while there is no implementation.

You may have had that implementation (an empty method) and then deleted it, without deleting the reference to it in the UI in Visual Studio. So open your Form in Visual Studio, click on the `TextBox1`, look for the value in the `TextChanged` property and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Error speaks everything, just add `TextBox1_TextChanged` method to `WebForm1` class.
You probably have deleted the method from .cs class while event `TextChanged` on the form is still registered with method `TextBox1_TextChanged`.
Either remove that registered event from the UI or add `TextBox1_TextChanged` event with proper parameters again in class

Comment: Adding the method if it is not needed is not the best way to go about it. Removing the unwanted reference would be better.

Comment: Also, adding the method could still not fix the issue. Removing the reference is the sure fire fix.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your aspx page. Search for that input and remove the event attribute containing TextBox1_TextChanged.