# Table cell code causes error

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following code generates an error:

```
<td> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>  </td>
```

And the error is:

> ...does not contain a definition for 'TextBox1_TextChanged' and no extension method 'TextBox1_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type  could be found

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking.  If it's related to code that you wrote, please show it.

Comment: okay , i already fix it @STLDeveloper

Comment: Probably dupe of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330841/compilation-error.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong: You've given it a method `TextBox1_TextChanged` to call when the text changes. Though clearly, you haven't defined that method anywhere. Remove that attribute entirely, or implement `TextBox1_TextChanged`.

Comment: yes already remove it,thank you, u guys help to solve my prob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove attribute `OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"` from textbox if you don't need. Or define one in codebehind with `protected`. or `public` access specifier.